# How does one secure api keys on sveltekit 1.0

Tags: security, sveltekit, ghost-blog

I am using ghost, i made an integration and i would like to hide the api key from the front-end. I do not believe i can set restrictions on the ghost cms (that would also work). And i do believe so +page.js files are run on the browser also, so im a little confused on how to achieve this?

Comment: [For integrating Ghost blogging with SvelteKit, you can find an example here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/tree/master/src/routes/blog).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interal sveltekit module `$env/static/private` ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private)) is how you use secure API keys. Sveltekit will not allow you to import this module into client code so it provides an extra layer of safety. Vite automatically loads your enviroment variables from `.env` files and `process.env` on build and injects your key into your server side bundle.

```js
import { API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
// Use your secret
```

Sveltekit has 4 modules for accessing enviroment variables

- `$env/static/private` (covered)
- `$env/static/public` accessiable by server and client and injected at build ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-public))
- `$env/dynamic/private` provided by your runtime adapter; only includes variables with that **do not** start with the your public prefix which defaults to `PUBLIC_` and can only be imported by server files ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private))
- `$env/dynamic/public` provided by your runtime adapter; only includes variables with that **do** start with the your public prefix which defaults to `PUBLIC_` ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-public))

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer i didnt know about this, i used a combination of this and +page.server.js files which is the equivalent of +page.js but only run on the server

Answer (score 4):

One common way to hide your third-party API key(s) from public view is to set up proxy API routes.

The general idea is to have your client (browser) query a proxy API route that you provide/host, have that proxy route query the third-party API using your credentials (API key), and pass on the results from the third-party API back to the client.

Because the query to the third-party API takes place exclusively on the back-end, your credentials are never exposed to the client (browser) and thus not visible to the public.

In your use case, you would have to create 3 dynamic endpoint routes to replicate the structure of Ghost's API:

`src/routes/api/[resource]/+server.js` to match `/posts/`, `/authors/`, `/tags/`, etc.:

```js
const API_KEY = <your_api_key>; // preferably pulled from ENV
const GHOST_URL = `https://<your_ghost_admin_domain>/ghost/api/content`;

export function GET({ params, url }) {
    const { resource } = params;
    const queryString = url.searchParams.toString();

    return fetch(`${GHOST_URL}/${resource}/?key=${API_KEY}${queryString ? `&${queryString}` : ''}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Version': '5.0' // Ghost API Version setting
        }
    });
}
```

`src/routes/api/[resource]/[id]/+server.js` to match `/posts/{id}/`, `/authors/{id}/`, etc.:

```js
const API_KEY = <your_api_key>; // preferably pulled from ENV
const GHOST_URL = `https://<your_ghost_admin_domain>/ghost/api/content`;

export function GET({ params, url }) {
    const { resource, id } = params;
    const queryString = url.searchParams.toString();

    return fetch(`${GHOST_URL}/${resource}/${id}/?key=${API_KEY}${queryString ? `&${queryString}` : ''}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Version': '5.0' // Ghost API Version setting
        }
    });
}
```

`src/routes/api/[resource]/slug/[slug]/+server.js` to match `/posts/slug/{slug}/`, `/authors/slug/{slug}/`, etc.:

```js
const API_KEY = <your_api_key>; // preferably pulled from ENV
const GHOST_URL = `https://<your_ghost_admin_domain>/ghost/api/content`;

export function GET({ params, url }) {
    const { resource, slug } = params;
    const queryString = url.searchParams.toString();

    return fetch(`${GHOST_URL}/${resource}/slug/${slug}/?key=${API_KEY}${queryString ? `&${queryString}` : ''}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Version': '5.0' // Ghost API Version setting
        }
    });
}
```

Then all you have to do is call your proxy routes in place of your original third-party API routes in your app:

```html
// very barebones example
<script>
    let uri;
    let data;

    async function get() {
        const res = await fetch(`/api/${uri}`);
        data = await res.json();
    }
</script>

<input name="uri" bind:value={uri} />
<button on:click={get}>GET</button>
{data}
```

Note that using proxy API routes will also have the additional benefit of sidestepping potential CORS issues.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hide the key.

[Ghost Content API Docs](https://ghost.org/docs/content-api/):

> These keys are safe for use in browsers and other insecure environments, as they only ever provide access to public data.

Comment: hmm i just checked the docs and it also says `Sites in private mode should consider where they share any keys they create.`

Answer (score 0):

In a .env file at the root of your SvelteKit directory, you can prefix the key names with VITE_ such as VITE_GHOST_CONTENT_API_KEY.

```
    //.env
     VITE_GHOST_CONTENT_API_KEY=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

This way you can import them like so:

```
//+page.server.ts
...
const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GHOST_CONTENT_API_KEY
...
```